# API cs-cart put request by react and axios

Tags: reactjs, api, cors, cs-cart

I use react in front-end and cs-cart API in back-end.
In the following code I used axios.put() as follows:

```
const data = JSON.stringify({
  "test1": "val1"
});

const config = {
  method: 'put',
  url: 'https://example.com/api/product/111',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Basic ${token}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  });
```

When sending a request, the browser sends a request with the OPTIONS method, which error: 405
Method Not Allowed returns.
And the original request (PUT) is not sent.

cs-cart is installed on the server. And the react project on localhost

[image: Options method detail]

[image: Request]

Comment: Method names are case-sensitive; try `PUT` (uppercase). If that doesn't solve it, show a full screenshot of the response to the preflight request.

Comment: @jub0bs - I tried but failed! I know the problem is solved by cs-cart codes! but how? I do not know!

Comment: @jub0bs : Screenshot OPTIONS:  [link](https://paste.pics/17e6037a9a77ae29364c4b217493cf8b)

Comment: It looks like that the server isn't configured to handle preflight requests.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure to understand the error correctly i.e

```
The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 405 Method Not Allowed response
status code indicates that the server knows the request method, but
the target resource doesnt support this method.

The server must generate an Allow header field in a 405 status code
response. The field must contain a list of methods that the target
resource currently supports.
```

Make sure that the server is able to understand how to interpret your request so the clients are able to proceed.

You can look at this in more detail below [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405).